# JSON_VALUE for Nameless JSON payload

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Just started playing with `JSON_VALUE` in SQL Server. I am able to pull values from name/value pairs of JSON but I happen to have an object that looks like this:

```
["first.last@domain.com"]
```

When I attempt what works for name/value pairs:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    jsonemail,
    JSON_VALUE(jsonemail, '$') as pleaseWorky
FROM MyTable
```

I get back the full input, not `first.last@domain.com`. Am I out of luck? I don't control the upstream source of the data. I think its a sting collection being converted into a json payload. If it was name: first.last@domain.com I would be able to get it with `$.name`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a JSON array. So you just need to specify its index, i.e 0.

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, jsonemail NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (jsonemail) VALUES
('["first.last@domain.com"]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
   , jsonemail AS [Before]
   , JSON_VALUE(jsonemail, '$[0]') as [After]
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------+-----------------------+
| ID |          Before           |         After         |
+----+---------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | ["first.last@domain.com"] | first.last@domain.com |
+----+---------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH):**

> - Array elements. For example, $.product[3]. Arrays are zero-based.

So you need `JSON_VALUE(..., '$[0]')` when the root is an array and you want the first value.

---

**To break it out into rows, you would need `OPENJSON`:**

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
   jsonemail
   ,j.[value] as pleaseWorky
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jsonemail) j
```